# Classify product attribute terms by type in Woocommerce product for display

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

I know that I can create attributes of color, size and etc. But for some reason, I had to combine 3 attributes into one and then displayed them differently.

Now, I've the attribute with the values :

pa_mixed : Red, Blue, Green, S, M, L, Children, Adult

But on the front end I have to display like :

Colors : Blue, Red

Size : M

Aged : Children

So far I have tried :

```
    if (!empty ($product->get_attribute('pa_mixed'))):
        $pa_mixed = $product->get_attribute('pa_mixed');
    else:
        $pa_mixed = "";
    endif;

    $size = array('S','M','L'); 
      
      if ( in_array( $size, $pa_mixed ) ) {
         //colors attributes
      }
      //etc
```

And finally I got lost

please help me to find the right way, thank you

Comment: _Why_ do you have to "combine" these three very different attributes, into one?

Comment: I am guessing, in `$pa_mixed` you are getting a value like `Red, M, Adult` or something similar now? Then `in_array( $size, $pa_mixed )` can of course never work. You would probably have to parse and "take apart" the value you are getting back, yourself here.

Comment: How does your `$pa_mixed` even look like? and it looks kinda wrong to be honest, since in array works like `in_array($needle, $haystack)`, but the array have to match specifcly, So if your sizes are off, by saying adding an XL, it goes wrong already. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php.

Comment: @CBroe   1. I already have a lot of attributes. 2. To simplify the display of filters. 3. Habitual factors. Generally (in us), Color, Size and age are top priorities so they can be grouped into one (I set -> multi dropdown on the filter button). However, I want on single product display to be separated. In addition to making the display more attractive, this also provides clear information.

Comment: @Dorvalla What's the best way to achieve what I want? Do I have to create 3 different attributes? If it does, it will add (more and more) to the list of filtering options that will (probably) confuse customers.

Comment: None of those points can convince me, that what you are trying to do actually makes sense. If you work _against_ the system like that, then don't be surprised if you run into additional problems later on. _"it will add (more and more) to the list of filtering options that will (probably) confuse customers"_ - then it would probably make more sense, to modify how your filtering logic works, rather than to _mess_ with such an integral part of how the core data model is supposed to work.

Comment: @CBroe Well, I will consider your suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated** *(handling fewer attribute classified types)*

Try the following, that will display product attributes, classified by type, in single product pages, below the short description:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'display_pa_mixed_classified_attributes', 25 );
function display_pa_mixed_classified_attributes() {
    global $product;

    $options = $product->get_attribute('pa_mixed'); // Attribute term names set in the product (string)
    $options = ! empty($options) ? explode(', ', $options) : array(); // Convert to an array

    if ( ! empty($options) ) {
        // Classifying "Mixed" attribute terms
        $data    = array(
            'colors' => array('label' => __('Colors', 'woocommerce'), 'options' => array('Red', 'Blue', 'Green')),
            'size'   => array('label' => __('Size', 'woocommerce'), 'options' => array('S', 'M', 'L')),
            'aged'   => array('label' => __('Aged', 'woocommerce'), 'options' => array('Children', 'Adult')),
        );

        $types   = array('colors', 'size', 'aged'); // Defined types
        $values  = $new_types = array(); // Initializing

        // Loop through the "Mixed" attributes term names set in the product
        foreach( $options as $option ) {
            foreach( $types as $type ) {
                if ( isset($data[$type]['options']) && in_array($option, $data[$type]['options']) ) {
                    $values[$type][] = $option;
                    $new_types[$type] = $type;
                }
            }
        }
        echo '<div class="attribute_pa_mixed" style="padding-bottom:16px">';

        // Display: Loop through classified types
        foreach( $new_types as $type ) {
            printf( '<div class="attribute-%s">
            <span class="label">%s :</span> <span class="options">%s</span>
            </div>', $type, $data[$type]['label'], implode(', ', $values[$type]) );
        }
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and work.

Based on this attributes, product settings:

[image]

I get the following display on a product *(single product page)*:

[image]

Comment: I'm getting an error message ->  Notice: Undefined index: colors in /home/belleza/public_html/wp-content/plugins/code-snippets/php/snippet-ops.php(582) : eval()'d code on line 1293

Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /home/belleza/public_html/wp-content/plugins/code-snippets/php/snippet-ops.php(582) : eval()'d code on line 1293
Colors : || 1293 -> </div>', $type, $data[$type]['label'], implode(', ', $values[$type]) ); ||

Comment: @carlozsan I don't have any issue as I am testing with `Blue, Red, M, Children` string that should be what you get from `$product->get_attribute('pa_mixed')` *(see my addition)*. Can you check what you get from `print_r($product->get_attribute('pa_mixed'));`?

Comment: Okay, please wait a moment, thank you

Comment: Sorry for keeping you waiting.

1. Following your instructions, I used this :  $options='Blue, Red, M, Children'; -> And it worked.

2. I'm have tried : 

 $options_test = array($product->get_attribute('pa_mixed')); 

  and in the next line

 $options = implode(',',$options_test);

  -> and this also works.

3. Getting an error message if: The attribute value contains only (ex) Red and Adult -> Undefined index: size in /home/...

4. So, which is the right way? Point 2 or is there another way? Thank you

Comment: Result print_r --> Adult, M, Red

Comment: Additional note: 

The first code you provide actually works. I was not meticulous saw a product that (incidentally) did not have a complete attribute value (Adult, M, Red), so finally got an error message as I explained in point 3.

When I see a product that has complete attribute values, the result is as I want (So please ignore point 2).

Now it remains only to eliminate the error message for products that do not have a full attribute value

Comment: Now it doesn't get an message error. But, the result is repeated to 3x  [results](https://prnt.sc/DPFFCKe5wEKh) or Colors : Blue, Colors : Blue, Colors : Blue

Comment: Finally, this is what I want. No more error message.  @LoicTheAztec, have a nice day :)